# Mark/Flag last non-zero (or specific) value in a vector

Tags: r

Seemingly simple question yet I can't figure it out nor find the answer.
I have the following data:

```
tibble(A = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0), 
       B = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2))
```

I now wish to mark/flag (Not extract) the last non-zero value(or the last time `A == 1`) in a separate column, per group `B`.
Ideally I would like to do so using dplyr:

```
DF %>% group_by(B) %>%
mutate(C = ???)
```

I've found lots of answers on how to extract this value, but none on how to flag it. The closest I found was `last(A[A==1])`, but this sets all C values equally. Instead I only want the last non-zero value per group marked.

My expected output would be something like:

```
tibble(A = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0), 
       B = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), 
       C = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0))
```

Comment: whats your expected output?

Comment: Silly of me, I've edited the question with the expected output.

Comment: @R.Iersel, I've edited my answer, please check, also in your expected output, why is it 1 at rownumber 5 for first group?

Comment: @KarthikS Yes the edited version is perfect, thank you! It is 1 at number 5 as I wanted to demonstrate it should mark the last non-zero value per group even if the last value isn't 1, which might not have been clear with my original tibble. I will edit it to make it clearer for those in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(B) %>% mutate(C = case_when(row_number() == max(which(A == 1)) ~ 1L, TRUE ~ 0L))
# A tibble: 14 x 3
# Groups:   B [2]
       A     B     C
   <dbl> <dbl> <int>
 1     0     1     0
 2     0     1     0
 3     0     1     0
 4     0     1     0
 5     1     1     0
 6     0     1     0
 7     1     1     1
 8     0     2     0
 9     1     2     0
10     1     2     0
11     0     2     0
12     0     2     0
13     1     2     1
14     0     2     0
```

Comment: Sadly no, this is similar to the "last(A[A==1])" I found, though that code marks the number itself not the index. I would like all values in the C column to be 0, except for the last non-zero value per group.

Comment: What about `mutate(C = 0, C[max(which(A == 1))] = 1)`?

Comment: The edited version works exactly as intended, thank you! @GregorThomas, this code gives me an error, I thought you maybe meant "== 1" but this simply returns FALSE to me in the extra column. But Karthik's solution works perfectly. Thank you!